# Material Design colors in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to implement Google Material Design, but I don’t understand the color values, like 100, 200, 500. What is the meaning of those values?
[Google Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette)
[image]

Provide tutorial link.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those numbers are the *shade* values. They are used to identify a color. It can be compared to other color systems, like Pantone. Whenever you specify colors, use the shade values, not the HEX values.
Additionally, some colors have accents. Those are identified by an A letter.

For instance: A style guide may list as primary color *Red 500*. The team knows where to look up and will use *#F44336* in their style sheets.

**tl;dr**
It’s the identifier/shade of the color.

Answer (score 0):

Accent colors should be used in secondary color palettes and not in the primary one. Accent colors are identified by an "A" character in front of the number which indeed identifies the color hues. Google recommends only to use one accent color for your secondary color palette and three hues for your primary color palette. Google also suggests to use 500 color hue as primary base color.

Take a look here: http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-ui-color-application

It's the same page you provided us with except it's scrolled down further to an example made by Google on how to create your color palettes.